# Number of messages still in azure servicebus queue

Tags: python, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I am trying to get the number of messages still in the ServiceBus queue in Python.

I am able to receive messages but I can only find [documentation to get the message count via the portal, CLI, or powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-counters), but not for the python SDK. Is there such a function or property?

```
from azure.servicebus import ServiceBusClient


with ServiceBusClient.from_connection_string(CONNECTION_STRING) as client:

with client.get_queue_receiver(QUEUE_NAME, max_wait_time=30) as receiver:

    msgs = receiver.receive_messages(2)
    for msg in msgs:
        receiver.complete_message(msg)
    number_of_retrieved_messages = len(msgs)

    number_of_messages_still_in_queue = ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking through the code of the Python SDK (the [Azure Service Bus client library for Python](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/main/sdk/servicebus/azure-servicebus)), it appears that there's a `ServiceBusAdministrationClient` that has a `get_queue_runtime_properties` method.

```py
queue_runtime_properties = await servicebus_mgmt_client.get_queue_runtime_properties(QUEUE_NAME)`
print("Message Count:", queue_runtime_properties.total_message_count)
```

*Example found in [async_samples/mgmt_queue_async.py](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/29c7a903010498ad9413b7be29e490624810f3f9/sdk/servicebus/azure-servicebus/samples/async_samples/mgmt_queue_async.py)

Implementation found in [management/_management_client.py](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/60a7f629d56a8380806df322d1d5a3fa1559b718/sdk/servicebus/azure-servicebus/azure/servicebus/management/_management_client.py#L284)*

Comment: seems to work, I still need further permissions (`HttpResponseError: Manage,EntityRead claims required for this operation.`) , but at least it doesn't throw any sytnax errors ;) Thanks!